# Why sox trim and split operations (based on silence) are too slow in Windows

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition, sox, libsox

I am trying to implement sox into a speech recognition program.
However it tooks nearly 10 seconds for sox to trim words in very simple sentence with 5-7 words (file size is also between 200-400kb)
it is unacceptaable.
What can I do, or which other options can be used for the same aim.
by the way the sox parameters I am using are

sox  -c 1 -r 16000  input.wav output.wav silence 1 0.5 1% 1 0.1 1% : newfile : restart

Comment: It's unlikely sox is slow, probably there is some other reason or your are running on some slow machine or something else is making the process slow. Probably you are accessing file over network with a slow filesystem. Here sox takes 0.4 seconds to process 20 minutes file of the size 15mb. You can profile your system with system profiler like oprofile to figure out where it spends the time.

Comment: it is really really interesting what you said. By the way I have Core i7 machine with 12 gb ram I dont think machine configuration is the answer and also file is local not network

Comment: Profiler is your friend

Comment: the thing is I have no idea how to use it or how to act if I find something wrong using profiler And the big problem which I didn't mentioned accidentally I use WINDOWS

Comment: Re: "how to act if I find something wrong using profiler". Provide the information here and ask for help? There could be many issues, check this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025114/sox-running-slow-using-a-processbuilder